# Problemas al visualizar campo tipo date in ASP.CORE NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datetime, dataannotations

Tengo en mi clase Paciente definido el campo fecha de nacimiento de tipo 'date'

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Fecha de Nacimiento del Paciente es Obligatorio.")]
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:dd-MM-yyyyy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public DateTime PAC_FECHA_NAC { get; set; }
```

Y en mi formulario lo tengo definido de la siguiente manera.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
    <input id="FecNacVal" asp-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_FECHA_NAC" type="date" placeholder="FECHA NAC." class="form-control"  min=@DateTime.Now asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" max=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")  />
    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_FECHA_NAC" class="text-danger"></span>
                                            </div>
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar el aplicativo me visualiza de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que estoy realizando de manera errónea que no me carga correctamente la fecha.

Comment: ¿Has visto qué dato le pasa el controlador a la vista? Porque es probable que sea un null...

Comment: Si efectivamente estaba pasando un null a mi campo `PAC_FECHA_NAC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como tu indicabas le pasaba un valor null al cargar el metodo OnGet.

```
  MODEL_PACIENTE = new PACIENTE
            {                  
                PAC_FECHA_NAC = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5),                  
            };
```

Comment: Excelente :D sigue desarrollando con todo el power 2.0!!!

Comment: Tal vez me puedas ayudar con otra pregunta?

Comment: Lanza la pregunta, en el sitio, por otro lado, te sugiero ver el workshop que hice sobre ASP.net MVC 5, los conceptos se mantienen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY